# NodeJS Multithreading and large data sets

Tags: node.js, multithreading, express

I have a sample node JS express rest application:

```
var express = require('express');
var logger = require('./src/logger');


var columnValue = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
var columnKey = "column";

var app = express();

var targetRecord = {};
logger.info("Creating Record...");
for (var i = 1; i <= parseInt("500"); i++) {
  targetRecord[columnKey+i]=columnValue;
}
logger.info("Creating Record complete.");

logger.info("Creating payload...");
var targetPayload = {};
var test = 500
for (var i = 1; i <= test; i++) {
  targetPayload["flight"+i]=targetRecord;
}
logger.info("Creating payload complete.");


/* GET home page. */
app.get('/flight', function (req, res) {
  logger.info("start"+req.query.id);
  if(req.query.id==2)
  {
      res.send("hello");
  }
  else {
  res.send(JSON.stringify(targetPayload));
  res.end();
  }

  logger.info("end"+req.query.id);
});

app.listen(8000, function () {
  logger.info('server listening on port ' + this.address().port);
});
```

The total data size to be returned is 28MB.

Using curl I see the following response times:

- 1 Client 3 seconds
- 2 clients both take 6 seconds
- 4 clients all take 11 seconds

Is this correct? 
will N number of client means N*3 seconds for all clients to respond? seems a little odd.

I have attempted to change the size of payload for 1 client by adding the id parameter of 2 to only return hello.

In that instance the id parametered client returns instantly and the other carry on as stated above.

Would anyone be able to shed some light as to what is occuring in my above example?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in node land. Your `JSON.stringify()` call is an expensive synchronous CPU operation, and Express is processing all of your requests in order. Therefore, Express is not responding to each client until the loop is unblocked. Try putting your `stringify` call inside  `setImmediate`to unblock the loop:

```
app.get('/flight', function (req, res) {
  logger.info("start"+req.query.id);
  if(req.query.id==2)
  {
      res.send("hello");
  }
  else {
    setImmediate(function(){
       res.send(JSON.stringify(targetPayload));
       res.end();
       logger.info("end"+req.query.id);
    })

  }


});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response - I have just tried to add this however it doesnt seem to have changed any of the response times. I have even tried removing the stringify all together and i still get similar responses.

Comment: If you removed the stringify, then what are you sending back?

Comment: `res.send(targetPayload);`

Comment: I have also added the set Immediate as advised this also didn't improve the performance.